# Access denied in a folder with Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When I try to access the `Documenti` folder with PowerShell I get an error

[image: error message]

I tried to change directory to `Documents` (English) instead of `Documenti` (Italian) and it works.

But the PowerShell suggest me `Documenti`, could it be a language configuration problem?

Comment: You can edit permission for `Documenti`, but should not access it in the first place. It is compatibility junction (reparse point).

Comment: That junction exists solely for backwards compatibility reasons. The actual folder is `Documents`. Since Microsoft wants to move away from localized documents folders the permissions on the junction forbid reading, but allow traversal, so that applications accessing items via a localized documents folder path won't fail, but users are discouraged from using the localized path.

Comment: OK so i can't fix this error?

Comment: @alvarofvr You can fix this error by using ``cd .\Documents\`` instead of ``cd .\Documenti\``.

Comment: OK, thank you man! Not the fix that i want but ok